# Instagram NSURL implementation with swift

Tags: swift, instagram, photo, url-scheme, custom-url

I have a photo editing app in swift, which needs the option to directly share to instagram.

Instagram gives ref to iphone hooks here but the implementation has proven difficult

Ideally the pages class has a button that should send the picture saved as pic.igo, (.igo assures instagram only) and brings the user directly to their post page on instagram with "pic.igo" already selected

Heres what hooks gives you, and I cant seem to find any modern use cases. The full page is in the link below

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://location?id=1"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}
```

So how do I put that into this function

```
@IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {


}
```

Iphone hooks doc

https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/

Notes
- checking to see if the app is already installed would help, but I really just need to find a way to make this function work and I can prob fumble through the rest

- "media?id=MEDIA_ID" from the documentation
     I assume that replaces the location part in their given snippet, but then how would I get the picture in view to be assigned to MEDIA_ID
- cut and paste leaves me with like 80 errors and no way of visual recovery

Comment: Don't use `NSURL`. Use `URL`.

Comment: Thats directly from their page, Im guessing thats what is meant by custom. Do you have an example that would work with just url?

Comment: Whose page? `NSURL` is Swift 2 and Objective-C. Since Swift 3 you use `URL`, not `NSURL`. But that's all irrelevant to your question. I'm just pointing it out.

Comment: While editing I mistakenly deleted the link, my mistake. https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/

Comment: Oops. That's Objective-C code that you've copied into your question from the documentation. I glossed over that detail initially.

Comment: So how would I write that in swift or how would I do it via obj-c? The videos they have on this subject are like 5 years old and Im still pretty new to swift so my understanding of obvious function structure isnt there yet. Im simply dont understand how to initiate and external view with a local url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking for the Swift translation of the ObjC code they provide, this is the result:

```
@IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {
    if let instagramURL = URL(string: "instagram://location?id=1"),
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(instagramURL)
    }
}
```

If you're having trouble converting code from ObjC, you can try some online converters, here are a couple options:

- https://objectivec2swift.com
- https://iswift.org/try

But the above is not for sharing to Instagram, if you want to share, that's what you need to do:

```
guard let instagramURL = URL(string: "instagram://app"),
    UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL) else {
        print("Instagram app is not installed")
        return
}

let yourIgoFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "igo")!
let documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: yourIgoFile)
documentController.uti = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"
documentController.presentOpenInMenu(from: view.bounds, in: view, animated: true)
```

Comment: I didnt even know it was in obj-c at first. Thank you. So then Ideally "instagram://location?id=1" becomes "instagram://media?id=MEDIA_ID", where I would set my current image as MEDIA_ID?

Comment: The code above is for opening a page in the Instagram app, you can't use that for sharing. I'll update my answer on how you can share.

Comment: Awesome, then so this would require my "yourIgoFile" to be the url of where it is stored on the web?

Comment: No, you cannot use remote URLs in the UIDocumentInteractionController, yourIgoFile would be the image file you saved locally in the phone.

Comment: I have the photo "test.igo" in my assets. It doesnt seem to understand me just writing in test.igo or test. So I assume I have to set it in some aspect, how would I assign my test photo the value to pass?

Comment: It expects an `URL` type, if it is in your assets, then that would be `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "igo")`

Comment: Could you update your top comment with that information? its now asking for separators and I think I just put in in incorrectly. I replaced "url: yourIgoFile" with the snippet you just provided

Comment: "url: " is part of the method signature, I'll update it

Comment: It wants to unwrap or force abort it in some aspect. Im getting a few errors on the "let documentController" line. Is this something I need to also set in my plist? its giving me, "Value of optional type 'URL?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'URL'" and Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'" and "Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'" –

Comment: If you're sure that the file exists, you can force unwrap it with `!`